# Image display React API without URL

Tags: reactjs, image, url, spoonacular

I have watched dozens of youtube videos, but do not come across my problem.

In React, I want to show a picture from the spoonacular API of which I only get the "name.png" in the console (i.e. not the full url).

At `setPicture(result.data.results[0].image)` I get the name of the picture in the console and I just need to get the url in front of it. I tried this with the following `` <img src={`https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_250x250/${picture}`} alt="food">; `` and I also tried to put the url in the useState but that doesn't work.

My complete code is as follows:

```
    const [food, setFood] = useState([]);
    const [picture, setPicture] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchFood() {
            const result = await axios.get(`https://api.spoonacular.com/food/ingredients/search?query=rice&number=20&apiKey=${apiKey}`);
            console.log(result);
            console.log("DATA:", result.data);
            console.log("DATA RESULTS:", result.data.results);
            // console.log("DATA RESULTS[0]:", result.data.results[0]);
            // console.log("DATA RESULTS[0]:", result.data.results[0].title);
            setFood(result.data.results[0]);
            setPicture(result.data.results[0].image)
        }

        fetchFood();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{food.name}</div>
            <img src={`https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_250x250/${picture}`} alt="food">;
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX supposed to be closed with `/>` (or `>` if it's have children) not `>;`

```js
<img src={`https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_250x250/${picture}`} alt="food" />
```

You can use `>;` if you only want to show one element, here's for example:

```js
function app() {
  return <img />;
}
```

It will work because it is end of `return`. And you already have it.

```
return (
  <div>
    <div>{food.name}</div>
    <img src={`https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_250x250/${picture}`} alt="food" />
  </div>
); // here
```